# High charts hidden data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[Please check this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ndKA.png)

How to fix this issue? I just want to see all the data without disabling other legends. If I disable "IT Services - Headcount" and "IT Services - Present", "Learning - Headcount" and "Learning - Present" will be shown (vice versa)

Comment: try to change `int` to `var` in your line no. 13

Comment: Can you paste the code here?